# How to save the results of an optimal power flow in MATPOWER for multiple runs?

Tags: matpower

I am using MATPOWER for optimal power flow of IEEE30 bus system. I am changing the real power generation of a particular bus 12 times and want to save the result 12 times also. But while doing so only the result of last run is saved in the result struct. The code is given:

```
P=xlsread('C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\output\sp.xlsx');
for h=1:12
P(h);
**mpc.gen(NG,PG)=P(h);**
mpopt = mpoption('pf.alg', 'NR', 'verbose', 1, 'out.all', 0);
results= runopf(mpc,mpopt);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store the result struct you get from each opf run in a struct array like so:

```
for h=1:12
P(h);
**mpc.gen(NG,PG)=P(h);**
mpopt = mpoption('pf.alg', 'NR', 'verbose', 1, 'out.all', 0);
results(h) = runopf(mpc,mpopt);
end
```

Adressing results should then be possible by calling e.g. `results(3).branch` or whatever you want to evaluate.